# Clojure Specter: how to find map keys that have specific value?

Tags: clojure, specter

Eg in a map:

```
{"test-1" 23,
 "test-2" 456,
 "test-3" 23}
```

How to find keys that have value `23`?

Comment: do you need specter for that input? it's not deeply nested structure tho.

Comment: Well that could as well be a trivialized example, and while easy to do that without specter, same could be said for many trivial data structures vs specter.  Yet the question itself is clear cut and if only lacks some "i have already tried" display of efford from OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find something using Specter, it is better to use **specter/select**.

```
(use 'com.rpl.specter)    

(select [ALL #(= (second %) 23) FIRST]
  {"test-1" 23,
   "test-2" 456,
   "test-3" 23})
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you don't need specter to do that, just filter by value. I.e:

```
(->> {:key-1 10
      :key-2 20
      :key-3 10}
      (filter (fn [[k v]] (= v 10)))
      (map first))
==>  [:key-1 :key-3]
```

A solution with Specter is:

```
(keys (specter/setval [specter/MAP-VALS #(not= 10 %)]
                       specter/NONE
                       {:key-1 10
                        :key-2 20
                        :key-3 10}))
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `seq` either because filter will seq its input anyway.